# c# - Objects not saving their own information

Tags: c#, oop, object

I have objects representing all of the planets in our solar system:

```
public static Planet Mercury = new Planet("Mercury");
public static Planet Venus = new Planet("Venus");
public static Planet Earth = new Planet("Earth");
public static Planet Mars = new Planet("Mars");
public static Planet Jupiter = new Planet("Jupiter");
public static Planet Saturn = new Planet("Saturn");
public static Planet Uranus = new Planet("Uranus");
public static Planet Neptune = new Planet("Neptune");
public static Planet Pluto = new Planet("Pluto");
```

I am then setting the values for each of the objects by running this function:

```
private static void SetPlanetInformation(Planet planet)
{
    Boolean MassDone = false;
    Boolean DistanceDone = false;

    Double Mass, Distance;

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the mass of {0} in kg", planet.GetPlanetName());
        MassDone = Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Mass);
        planet.SetPlanetMass(Mass);

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the distance of {0} from the sun in m", planet.GetPlanetName());
        DistanceDone = Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Distance);
        planet.SetPlanetDistance(Distance);

    } while (MassDone == false || DistanceDone == false);
}
```

When I run the program, I have it set to output all of the values for each object in turn.  However, it only outputs the values for the last object (pluto) for each object, despite them being printed separately.

```
Console.WriteLine("Mass of {0} is {1} kg, and the distance from the sun is {2} m.", Mercury.GetPlanetName(), Mercury.GetPlanetMass(), Mercury.GetPlanetDistance());
Console.WriteLine("Mass of {0} is {1} kg, and the distance from the sun is {2} m.", Venus.GetPlanetName(), Venus.GetPlanetMass(), Venus.GetPlanetDistance());
Console.WriteLine("Mass of {0} is {1} kg, and the distance from the sun is {2} m.", Earth.GetPlanetName(), Earth.GetPlanetMass(), Earth.GetPlanetDistance());
Console.WriteLine("Mass of {0} is {1} kg, and the distance from the sun is {2} m.", Mars.GetPlanetName(), Mars.GetPlanetMass(), Mars.GetPlanetDistance());
Console.WriteLine("Mass of {0} is {1} kg, and the distance from the sun is {2} m.", Jupiter.GetPlanetName(), Jupiter.GetPlanetMass(), Jupiter.GetPlanetDistance());
Console.WriteLine("Mass of {0} is {1} kg, and the distance from the sun is {2} m.", Saturn.GetPlanetName(), Saturn.GetPlanetMass(), Saturn.GetPlanetDistance());
Console.WriteLine("Mass of {0} is {1} kg, and the distance from the sun is {2} m.", Uranus.GetPlanetName(), Uranus.GetPlanetMass(), Uranus.GetPlanetDistance());
Console.WriteLine("Mass of {0} is {1} kg, and the distance from the sun is {2} m.", Neptune.GetPlanetName(), Neptune.GetPlanetMass(), Neptune.GetPlanetDistance());
Console.WriteLine("Mass of {0} is {1} kg, and the distance from the sun is {2} m.", Pluto.GetPlanetName(), Pluto.GetPlanetMass(), Pluto.GetPlanetDistance());
```

Please could someone help me understand why each planet is not retaining the information that it is provided, rather than just taking all of the information from the last planet for each planet.

Thanks

EDIT:

The class Planet is:
    public class Planet
    {
        private static string PlanetName;
        private static double PlanetMass;
        private static double PlanetDistance;

```
    public Planet(string name)
    {
        PlanetName = name;
    }

    public void SetPlanetName(string name)
    {
        PlanetName = name;
    }

    public string GetPlanetName()
    {
        return PlanetName;
    }

    public void SetPlanetMass(double mass)
    {
        PlanetMass = mass;
    }

    public double GetPlanetMass()
    {
        return PlanetMass;
    }

    public void SetPlanetDistance(double distance)
    {
        PlanetDistance = distance;
    }

    public double GetPlanetDistance()
    {
        return PlanetDistance;
    }
}
```

However, it was pointed out that PlanetName, PlanetMass and PlanetDistance shouldn't be static, so I have changed it now.

Comment: First, why are you doing the Java thing of `Get` and `Set` and not simply using [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)? Second, how could we possibly guess what this isn't working when you haven't provided a [MCVE]. We don't have the implementations of SetPlanetMass and SetPlanetDistance, and we don't have the implementations of GetPlanetMass, and GetPlanetDistance.

Comment: Also, if you defined `Planet` as a  struct, passing it to `SetPlanetInformation` would pass it by value and not by reference, so only the copy being used in `SetPlanetInformation` would be changed.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you've defined Planet's properties as `static`.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the implementation of `Planet`. It is impossible to answer otherwise.

Comment: @itsme86 statoc was the issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Planet
{
    private string PlanetName;
    private double PlanetMass;
    private double PlanetDistance;

    public Planet(string name)
    {
        PlanetName = name;
    }

    public void SetPlanetName(string name)
    {
        PlanetName = name;
    }

    public string GetPlanetName()
    {
        return PlanetName;
    }

    public void SetPlanetMass(double mass)
    {
        PlanetMass = mass;
    }

    public double GetPlanetMass()
    {
        return PlanetMass;
    }

    public void SetPlanetDistance(double distance)
    {
        PlanetDistance = distance;
    }

    public double GetPlanetDistance()
    {
        return PlanetDistance;
    }
}
```

PlanetName, PlanetMass and PlanetDistance shouldn't have been static.